# adding colors to simple cursor adapter list view

Tags: android, textview, simplecursoradapter

I was wondering what would be the best way to add color to each entries on the list that was created with simplecursoradapter? The following codes created a listview, using SimpleCursorAdapter, but the color of the text are all default grey. What I would like to do is to change the color of the text  in R.id.rowTitle, and R.id.rowName to different colors depending on the date.

```
    Cursor cursor = database.getTitles();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] columns = { SQLController.TITLE,
    SQLController.COLUMN_NAME, SQLController.DATE,
    };

    int to[] = {R.id.rowTitle, R.id.rowName,R.id.rowDate};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.rows, cursor, columns, to);

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: uff so you should create class that will `extends` from `SimpleCursorAdapter`, then create design pattern `Holder` to hold each row and finally in `getView()` method of you `CursorAdapterClass that will `extends` from `SimpleCursorAdapter` manually will set color as you want. I can add here my code of this but it has a little more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted the different items to be different colors, you could just do a custom row layout.

However, since you want to set it based on the content of the data, you will need to create a custom adapter (extend Simpl
eCursorAdapter) and put an `if` statement in there to check the date and set your color for each textview using `textview.setTextColor(color_ref);`

[Tutorial](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/)

Comment: if i create the custom class that extents the cursor adapter, then i would just call that class instead of the simple cursor adapter?

Comment: thanks i got it now. i was trying to do it without making another class so i got really confused as to how to do it.